# add contact form to static block in magento

Tags: forms, magento, contacts

how do i add default magento contact form to a static block?

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

doesn't seem to work.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found this which helped. the WYSIWYG editor was stripping out the code earlier.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/